# Unformat NTFS formatted LVM partition

Tags: disk-formatting

I accidentally formatted my LVM partition as NTFS. Now my data is lost.

How do I unformat?

Answer (score 0):

Look like fsck.ext4 saved my day. Although it spammed my terminal, i got my drive fixed.